# How to print data to ListTile(title: )?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm new to flutter

How do I print the data from getAge() to ListTile(title: )?

Here's the code:

```
const Divider(),
      const ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.face),
        title: Text(''),
        subtitle: Text('Age'),
      ),
    ];
    return ListView(children: listTiles);
  }
}

void getAge() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateTime birthday = DateTime.parse('1985-8-13');

  final age = now.year -
      birthday.year -
      (now.month > birthday.month
          ? 0
          : now.month == birthday.month
              ? now.day >= birthday.day
                  ? 0
                  : 1
              : 1);
  print(age);
}
```

Here's the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first issue is your time format, your month should be `08`, then return age from `getAge()`:

```
String getAge() {//<-- add this
      final DateTime now = DateTime.now();

      final DateTime birthday = DateTime.parse('1985-08-13');//<-- change month to 08

      final age = now.year -
          birthday.year -
          (now.month > birthday.month
              ? 0
              : now.month == birthday.month
                  ? now.day >= birthday.day
                      ? 0
                      : 1
                  : 1);

      print(age);
      return age.toString();//<-- add this
    }
```

then call it like this, don forgot to remove `const` before `ListTile`:

```
ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.face),
    title: Text(getAge()), //<-- add this
    subtitle: Text('Age'),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't "print" to a Widget. you provide it by making it return from the function. Change your function to

```
String getAge() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateTime birthday = DateTime.parse('1985-8-13');

  final age = now.year -
      birthday.year -
      (now.month > birthday.month
          ? 0
          : now.month == birthday.month
              ? now.day >= birthday.day
                  ? 0
                  : 1
              : 1);
  return age.toString();
}
```

And then use like

```
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.face),
    title: Text(getAge()),
    subtitle: Text('Age'),
  ),
```

Comment: I got an error to final DateTime birthday = DateTime.parse('1995-8-12');

Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid date format
1995-8-12)

Comment: @R.MadridJr. as I mentioned in my answer, you need to change your month to 08.

Answer (score 0):

```
int intAge = 0; //intialize age here

@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getAge(); //call in the initState function, it will be called first
}

void getAge() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateTime birthday = DateTime.parse('1985-8-13');

  final age = now.year -
      birthday.year -
      (now.month > birthday.month
          ? 0
          : now.month == birthday.month
              ? now.day >= birthday.day
                  ? 0
                  : 1
              : 1);
  intAge = age; //here assign value to intAge
}

const Divider(),
      const ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.face),
        title: Text(intAge.toString()),//change to String
        subtitle: Text('Age'),
      ),
    ];
    return ListView(children: listTiles);
  }
}
```